# AWS ALB health check pass HTTP but not Websocket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

I have an application deployed in a Docker Swarm which have two publicly reachable services, HTTP and WS.

I created two target groups, one for each service, and the registered instances are the managers of the Docker Swarm. Then I created the ALB and added two HTTPS listeners, each one pointing to the specific target group.

Now comes the problem. The HTTP health check passes without no problem, but the Websocket check is always unhealthy, and I don't know why. According to http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-listeners.html, using a HTTP/HTTPS listener should work for WS/WSS as well.

In the WS check, I have tried as path both `/` and the path the application is actually using `/ws`. Neither of them passes the health check.

It's not a problem related to firewall either. Security groups are wide open and there are no iptables rules, so connection is possible in both directions.

I launched the websocket container out of Docker Swarm, just to test if it was something related to Swarm (which I was pretty sure it was not, but hell.. for testing's sake), and it did not work either, so now I'm a little out of hope.

What configuration might I be missing, so that HTTP services work but Websocket services don't?.

**UPDATE**

I'm back with this issue, and after further researching, the problem seems to be the Target Group, not the ALB per se. Reading through the documentation http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-target-groups.html, I had forgotten to enable the stickiness option. However, I just did, and the problem persists.

**UPDATE 2**

It looks like the ELB is not upgrading the connection from HTTP to WebSocket.

Comment: have you resolved the issue?

Comment: @Kostanos nope, still struggling with this issue

Comment: @yzT do you have a workaround ? I can think of the alternative to run a mini-webserver to perform the health-checks but meh...

Comment: @CyrilDuchon-Doris we are no longer using websockets, so don't know if something has changed on the AWS side.

Answer (score 1):

ALBs do not support websocket health checks per:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/target-group-health-checks.html

" Health checks do not support WebSockets."

The issue is that despite AWS claiming that the ALB supports HTTP2 in fact it downsamples everything to HTTP1 and then does it's thing then upgrades it to HTTP2 again which breaks everything.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. When the ALB checks the WS service it receives an HTTP status of 101 (Switching protocols) from it. And, as noted in other answers, that's not a good-enough response for the ALB. I attempted changing the matcher code in the health check config but it doesn't allow anything outside the 200-299 range.
In my setup I had Socket.io running on top of Express.js so I solved it by changing the Socket.io path (do not confuse path with namespace) to `/ws` and let the Express.js answer the requests for `/`. Pointed the health check to `/` and that did it.